# Title in black background rectangle and labels in a white background rectangle

Tags: html

The code below creates the title of the event and three lables, it works fine but I couldn't find out how to create a black rectangle to put the title inside it as in the attached image. Do I have to create a canvas and put the labels inside it?

Besides I could not find out how to center the title and three labels with a margin to show it more centered

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Event registration form</title>
    <style>
        label
        {
            display : block;
            margin  : 0 0 1rem;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Event registration form</h1>
<label>
    Number 1
    <input type="number" id="age" min="0"/>
</label>
<label>
    Number 2
    <input type="number" id="tso" min="0"/>
</label>


<label>
    Number 3 
    <input type="number" id="fim" min="0"/>
</label>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it via css.

**Black rectangle with white font:**

Add a class `bg-dark` to your `h1` and set the background color to dark and the font color to white:

```css
.bg-dark{
  background-color: #000;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
}
```

**Tag alignment:**
Add a wrapper for the label and the input and use flexbox ( [check the browser compatibility just in case](https://caniuse.com/flexbox)).

Check the snippet.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');

*{
/*Just changed the font, so it looks nice, you can use your own font*/
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.bg-dark{
  background-color: #000;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
}
.form-style{
  margin-left: 2rem;
}
.input-style{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:start;
  padding-top: 0.7rem;
  padding-bottom:0.7rem;
}
.input-style label{
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  text-align: start;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.input-style .input-wrapper{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.input-style .input-wrapper input{
  border: 2px solid #f4f4f4;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: #d4d4d4;
  color: #333;
  padding: 7px 13px;
  padding-left: 13px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="bg-dark">Event registration form</h1>
<form class="form-style">
  <div class="input-style">
    <label for="age"> Number 1</label>
    <div class="input-wrapper">
      <input type="number" id="age" placeholder="age here" min="0"/>
      <small>Age</small>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-style">
    <label for="tso">Number 2</label>
    <div class="input-wrapper">
      <input type="number" placeholder="tso here" id="tso" min="0"/>
      <small>Tso</small>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-style">
    <label>Number 3</label>
    <div class="input-wrapper">
      <input type="number" placeholder="fim here" id="fim" min="0"/>
      <small>Fim</small>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: If you're interested in css flexbox, you can try [flexbox froggy](https://flexboxfroggy.com/), it's a game to learn how to use the flex properties. Also, [grid garden](https://cssgridgarden.com/) to learn about grids.